# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_intl.dll'

Tags: php

In order to access our server, we have to do following steps.

1. Run MySQL57
2. Run in Git console: gulp watch
3. Run in Git console: `php bin/console server:run localhost:8001`

I have no problem with the first two steps, but when I run the third step, I am getting the following error:

> $ php bin/console server:run localhost:8001 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_intl.dll' - The specified
>   module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'ext\php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.  in
>   Unknown on line 0 Could not open input file: bin/console

I googled this warning, but all answers related to wamp and xampp, so I couldn't find my answer.

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: i think you may miss that `lib` plz be load it. here we go https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/unable-to-load-or-find-php-extension-php_intl-dll

Comment: I checked this link before, but I failed in the first task:

cd  \WampDeveloper\Components\Php

I believe it is because I do not have WampDeveloper. I have MySQL5.7 instead.